# Vuex: Setter is not working and input doesn't write?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have used the Two-way Computed Property in Vuex, and the setter is not working properly. When I write inside the input, it just shows up one letter at the time. I'll show you what I have done with code down bellow. I do get the data. The mutation is stored in store and same with the state.

Vue file:

```html
<div style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
  <input id="phone" v-model="phone" type="text">
</div>
```

```ts
computed: {
  phone: {
    get (): any {
      const contactUsInfo: ContactUsInfo = this.$store.getters['billing/getContactInfo'];
      return contactUsInfo.phone;
    },
    set (phone: any) {
      this.$store.commit('billing/setContactData', phone);
    }
  }
}
```

The mutation:

```ts
setContactData(state: BillingState, payload: ContactUsInfo) {
  state.contactUsInfo = payload;
}
```

The getter:

```ts
getContactInfo(state: BillingState): ContactUsInfo {
  return state.contactUsInfo;
}
```

Comment: Show `billing/getContactInfo` getter code.

Comment: @Styx I have edited now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store commit writes into `contactUsInfo`, you store getter returns `contactUsInfo`, but `phone` getter tries to return `contactUsInfo.phone`.

I think it should be like this:

```js
computed: {
  phone: {
    ...
    set (phone: any) {
      this.$store.commit('billing/setContactData', { phone });
    }
  }
}
```

```js
setContactData(state: BillingState, payload: ContactUsInfo) {
  state.contactUsInfo = Object.assign({}, state.contactUsInfo, payload);
}
```

Comment: @IssaChii Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: True :)) Done it now!